# Как из скрипта на Питоне послать письмо с вложением?

Tags: python, smtp

Нужен простейший пример посылки письма с вложением через внешний SMTP сервер, например, smtp.yandex.ru.

Comment: если [почтовое вложение это картинка, то можно послать его с письмом так, чтобы оно показывалось прямо внутри письма (gmail)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20485764/4279)

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/send-email-smtp-python
https://habr.com/ru/company/pechkin/blog/281915/ .
Тут подробней уже некуда. Собственно, сам код совпадает с предыдущим ответом, но подробно объяснён каждый оператор.

Comment: это первый вопрос ruSo?

Comment: @Антон похоже, что да.

Comment: Я не опоздал случаем?

Comment: это первый вопрос не ruSo, а ХэшКода :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders
import os

filepath = "/path/to/file"
basename = os.path.basename(filepath)
address = "name@server"

# Compose attachment
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(filepath,"rb").read() )
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename)

# Compose message
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = address
msg['To'] = address
msg.attach(part)

# Send mail
smtp = SMTP_SSL()
smtp.connect('smtp.yandex.ru')
smtp.login(address, 'password')
smtp.sendmail(address, address, msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: [Проверка ssl сертификатов выключена по умолчанию](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/) в версиях Питона меньше 2.7.9 (вышла в Декабре 2014). Можно свой [подкласс SMTP_SSL() написать, который проверяет сертификаты](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12550481/4279)