# smtplib в Python c smtp.yandex.ru

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

Юзаю Python 3.4.3. Хочу написать простенький скрипт, который будет отсылать на заданный ящик текстовую информацию. Нашёл : [следующий пример](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email). В режиме интерпретатора ввожу:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)
```

И на второй строчке интерпретатор наглухо виснет. Для Яндекса инфу о сервере брал [отсюда](https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients.xml).

UPD: если использовать то же для Gmail:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

То всё норм. Однако хочется (т.е. имеется ящик) подключаться к Яндексу. Возможно это?

UPD2: если для Яндекса юзать порт 587, то вторая строчка тоже проходит. Однако третья:

```
server.login("youremailusername", "password")
```

Приводит к поднятию эксепшена `smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected`

UDP3: нашёл [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC). Делаю так:

```
import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
smtp.connect('smtp.yandex.ru')
```

И вываливается `ssl.SSLEOFError`

UPD4: Нашёл [эту ссылку](http://www.wisereport.ru/python-mail/) и сделал так:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru:465')
server.login('login', 'pass')
```

И всё заработало. Заработало в том смысле, что пришло `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError` с сообщением, суть которого заключается в том что я веду себя как робот и мне надо привязать номер мобильного чтобы система перестала видеть во мне робота. Видимо, защита от подбора пароля.

Comment: опубликуйте Ваше решение (`smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)` вместо `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)`) как ответ (если оно работает) -- [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Не нужно рабочее решение в вопросе размещать.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу прям утверждать что оно заработало. Суть в том, что по идее, если бы не защита Яндекса (видимо, от подбора пароля брутфорсом), оно бы наверно заработало бы, однако из-за защиты Яндекса я не могу это проверить.

Единственное преимущество решения из последнего апдейта перед предыдущими состоит в том, что строчка `server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru:465')` позволила успешно подконнектиться к серверу. А вот залогиниться не дало.

Потому думаю, в данной ситуации лучше вместо Яндекса попробовать использовать другой сервис.

Comment: Просто как бы основная цель заключалась в том, чтобы отправить сообщение с помощью сервера. Этого добиться не удалось.

Comment: Такая же проблема с gmail и smtplib. Мое решение было таким - зашел в аккаунт Google и отключил в настройках проверку безопасности. Все остальные решения не помогли.

Comment: Вот [код, который работает с несколькими email провайдерами.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/369479/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Xyanight (надеюсь я его позвал): для Gmail

```
import smtplib

def sendEMail(text):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("login", "pass")
    message = "\r\n".join([
        "From: от кого",
        "To: кому",
        "Subject: тема",
        "",
        str(text)
    ])
    server.sendmail("от кого", "кому", message)
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Для яндекса у меня получилось пройти аутентификацию AUTH PLAIN через SSL соединение.
Работает такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import smtplib as smtp
from getpass import getpass

email = input('введите почту: \n')
password = getpass('введите пароль: ')
dest_email = input('введите адрес получателя: \n')
subject = input('тема письма: \n')
email_text = input('текст письма: \n' )

message = 'From: {}\nTo: {}\nSubject: {}\n\n{}'.format(email,
                                                       dest_email, 
                                                       subject, 
                                                       email_text)

server = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo(email)
server.login(email, password)
server.auth_plain()
server.sendmail(email, dest_email, message)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня вот так заработало для Яндекса:

```
import smtplib

email = 'some@mail.ru'
password = 'some_pass'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 587)
server.ehlo() # Кстати, зачем это? 
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)

dest_email = 'another@mail.ru'
subject = 'Booking from chatbot'
email_text = 'Text'
message = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s' % (email, dest_email, subject, email_text)

server.set_debuglevel(1) # Необязательно; так будут отображаться данные с сервера в консоли
server.sendmail(email, dest_email, message)
server.quit()
```